# How can I make my plot like this plot style picture

Tags: plotting, labeling, style, plot-themes

I would like to have all of my plots like this picture here, How I should add such as PlotStyle -> , PlotTheme -> and AxesLabel -> etc,.. I would like to see for this example Sin[x], Sin[2x], Sin[3x]

Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2*x], Sin[3*x]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Dashed}, AxesLabel -> {x, "Sin"}]

[image]

Comment: Realistically though, you must have tried something more than just the code you showed, right? `Gridlines`, `AxesLabels` or `FrameLabels`, etc?

Comment: There are virtually infinite possibilities for styling plots. It would be not very useful to discuss all of them on stackexchange.  Much better is to focus on one specific problem at a time. Therefore, what exactly feature of the shown plot you do not know how to achieve  despite reading the documentation, trying and searching on this forum?